# Wrong TimeZone in DataTable

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, database-table

I Have a web site, which is on server1. It uses web service, which is on server2. Web service uses database, which is on server3.

Server1 server2 and server3 has different timezone, so when I get datatable via web service, Datetime type column has different time value.

For example,

if in database I have a record (date type) '2010-03-24-12:00:00', on web site I get '2010-03-24-13:00:00'

I tried to change column's "DateTimeMode" but problem was not solved.

Comment: Are you sure the values aren't already stored wrong now? Because the DateTimeMode did it for us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I have always stored datetime values in my databases as UTC and left it up to the client to adjust accordingly to its associated timezone.  .NET 3.5 makes this timezone adjustment very easy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with serialising a DateTime and WCF.

The best solution is to always store the DateTime as UTC in the database.  Then when reading the DateTime from SQL always use DateTime.Specify to specify a DateTimeKind.Utc.

Answer (score 1):

Using Universal time or GMT should cure that problem.